# Confusion dealing with inserting struct into linked list (C)

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, nodes

I have an assignment with some functions given to me and others to be implemented myself. One of the functions I do myself is where I add individual parameters to a struct object, then I call an insert function (that is provided) to put that object into a linked list. 
However, one of the parameters that the insert function has me lost.

Here's the .h's.

```
struct node{
    Task *task;
    struct node *next;
};
```

```
typedef struct task{
    char *name;
    int tid;
    int priority;
    int burst;
} Task;
```

And here's the start of my add function where I create the object and intend to insert it into the linked list.

```
void add(char *name, int priority, int burst){

    Task task1 = (Task){.name = name, .priority = priority, .burst = burst};
    //insert() here
}
```

However, insert's parameters are confusing me.

```
void insert(struct node **head, Task *task);
```

I know that task1 would be the second parameter, but I don't know what to do for the first one. How do I call insert inside my add function?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep a list head variable someplace, initialized to `NULL`, e.g.:

```
struct node *list_head = NULL;
```

Then pass the address to your function:

```
insert(&list_head, task);
```

The reason you pass the address is so that `insert` can modify it to point to the new list head.

Comment: Ahhh. The double ** was confusing me. Thank you very much.
btw, I borrowed that method of adding parameters to a struct object from an old Stack Overflow post. Are there any issues with it?

Comment: Do you mean the initialization of `task1`?  That was one of the extensions that was added to C at some point to allow named structure field initialization.  Before that, you could only specify a sequence of field values (with no names).

Comment: Yes, I was referring to task1. I should have been more specific. I couldn't find many examples of it.

Comment: It's one of the features that was added in C99.  I found [this explanation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization) which might help.

Comment: I'm glad they added that feature. Thanks again for everything.